# Radio button can not be selected

Tags: php, mysql, radio-button

My problem is that I can not select radio buttons. I am using php mysql and create radio buttons in while loop for mysql_fetch_array function. Here is the code:

```
<div class="alert alert-info">
     <label id="dataFlow">
          <?php if($detailPage == TRUE && $detailType == "poll"){ ?>
              <!-- survey part -->                                
              <h3><?php echo $pollData['pollContent']; ?></h3>
                   <form id="pollForm" method="post" action="">
                        <p>
                             <?php while($pollAnswerData = $pollAnswerDataSql->fetch_assoc()) {
                                                echo '<input type="radio" id="' . $pollAnswerData['pollquestionId'] . '" name="pollAnswer" />' . $pollAnswerData['pollquestionContent'] . '<br/>'; 
                                            } ?>      
                                        </p>
                       <input type="submit" name="submitButton" id="submitButton" value="Gönder"/>
                       </form>
                 <?php } else if($detailPage == TRUE && $detailType == "post") { ?>
                  <h4><?php echo $postData['postContent']; ?></h4>
             <?php } else { 
                  listFlowData();
             } ?>
      </label>                            
 </div>
```

What is the problem in here?

Comment: entire form within `label` tag...Surprising!!!

Comment: the structure of your program is wrong.apart from that what error you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

Input elements (radio or checkbox) are not selected but checked. To show an element in checked state in the browser, you have to add a boolean "checked" attribute to the element.

```
<input type="radio" checked="checked" id="..." name="..." value="..."/>
```

Be aware that the browser only sends the values of the checked elements to your server side script. To recognize unchecked elements you have to use an internal list.

For radio inputs that means only if one of the elements was clicked by the user (or checked using the attribute) the named-parameter will exists in the form request.

Comment: checked ="checked" is not required when you are submitting the data through radio button .it may be required in the edit page where you want to show the option user has checked or selected.

Answer (score 0):

seems like You are missing value attribute

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

```
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">
```

Answer (score 0):

You may change this line of code

```
echo '<input type="radio" id="' . $pollAnswerData['pollquestionId'] . '" name="pollAnswer" />' . $pollAnswerData['pollquestionContent'] . '<br/>';
```

to this.

```
echo '<input type="radio" id="' . $pollAnswerData['pollquestionId'] . '" name="pollAnswer" value="' . $pollAnswerData['pollquestionId'] . '"/>' . $pollAnswerData['pollquestionContent'] . '<br/>';
```

hope $pollAnswerData['pollquestionId'] is a unique value. Radio box is not selected because you do not insert value in radio box. You should insert value, which necessarily should be change on each loop repetition.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in Google chrome you may not be facing any problems. in Firefox, there is a problem. and the problem I figured out is that your form is within a label.
remove the label tag and it should be all fine. 
even the non unique ID does not hurt in any browser(tested on chrome, Firefox and IE9)

below is the HTML I have been testing for you. uncomment the label and you will get the problem. hope it helps.

**NOTE:** The ID of each radio button is kept deliberately same to demonstrate that browser ignore this.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<!-- <label id="dataFlow"> -->
<form id="pollForm" method="post" action="">
<input type = "radio" id="rdo1" name = "poll_radio" value = "dsfsr"/>111<br/>
<input type = "radio" id="rdo1" name = "poll_radio" value = "rsddf"/>222<br/>
<input type = "radio" id="rdo1" name = "poll_radio" value = "rsfdf"/>333<br/>
<input type = "radio" id="rdo1" name = "poll_radio" value = "rshdf"/>444<br/>
<input type="submit" name="submitButton" id="submitButton" value="Gender"/>
</form>
<!-- </label> -->
</body>
</html>
```